# Is it possible to get authorization_code in OAuth 2.0 without web browser in Java?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0

As I understand, in authorization code flow we need to get authorization code and use it to get token after. We can get this code only when user confirms specified access. After that browser redirects us to redirect_uri and response will contain authorization code as parameter. So, the question: is it possible to get this authorization code without browser or any self made UI? Can we get it in application after correct request to, for example `https://mysite.tuz/authorize` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are using authorization code flow, the client requires a user agent (i.e browser or mobile app) to get the authorization code from the authorization server.

The whole purpose of using authorization code is that it can be passed via the user's web browser (user agent) instead of passing the access tokens directly via the web browser (user agent) which is not desired. Using authorization code,the Client then can directly retrieve an Access Token from the authorization server.

So the user agent is required to get the authorization code and act as an intermediary between client and authorization server.

If you do not require a browser then authorization code flow may not the correct choice. OAuth 2.0 supports several different grants i.e ways of retrieving an Access Token. Deciding which one is suited for your case depends mostly on your Client's type.

This might help you in deciding which flow to use
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use

Comment: I'm using google auth and want to do it without browser, do you have any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use client credentials to obtain token without browser or any client. But if you need to use user credentials to get access token and id token of the user without browser or mobile app you need to implement you own client which will do the necessary logic for you and fetch the token for you. I already did it in java for the testing purpose. I don't know why you need to do it but you can implement your own client in almost any programming language . But in case you will decide to go this way you have to handle lot of things.

1. I expect your authorization server requires Proof-Key for Code
   Exchange (PKCE) - so first of all before you start to communication
   with server you have to create code verifier and code challenge
   (google can help you with that :) in java it is quite simple)
2. Then you should start communication with server sending get request to url which ends with 'auth' you should send query params as: response_type (which is 'authorization_code' in your case), redirect_uri, client_id, code_verifier, code_challenge, scope, code_challenge_method (probably 'S256')
3. Then you receive I think two redirects from server so it is better to have some client in java which will automatically call those redirects. I used apache http client for my implementation. It has lot of features.
4. After successful redirect server will return login page to your client. It depends on authorization server but in this page you should put the data as username and password and submit the page. I have simply parsed the returned page and get the url for user authentication from it and simply make post request to that url with user credentials data sent in encoded form entity. In apache http client you will have all cookies from previous communication set (until you close the client) since apache http client automatically set all cookies returned in previous communication from server.
5. After make authentication request server will send you two redirects and you can store those redirects int http client context which you will provide for http client when you call authentication url.
6. In the last redirect there will be query parameter sent be server named "CODE" this is really important for you since you will use it to get token from the server
7. And finally you have to make one last post request to authorization server with url ended as token. So make a post request with GRANT_TYPE, REDIRECT_URI, CODE (you received in previous redirect), CLIENT_ID, CODE_VERIFIER (you have generated at the beginning);
8. Then authorization server will send you token and that's all